# How should my texture sampler be for rendering a bitmap font/sprite?

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, sprite, directx-11

I have a texture and was curious as to what the texture sampler should be for sampling the sprite texture? I am using DirectX11, though if you know what it should be for DX9/10, I believe it is transferable.

I tried

```
AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP
AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP
AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP
ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER
Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_POINT
MaxAnisotropy = 1;
MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;
MinLOD = 0;
MipLODBias = 0;
```

Although when rendering, there appeared to be artifacts and it did not seem as clear as it should be.

This is an example of what the artifcats are. The top text with a light blue background you can see artifacts (for example, the A and C). The bottom text with the black background is the origin image.

[image]

Comment: Use a LINEAR or higher filter.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Unfortunately LINEAR is still giving more artifacts. Do you perhaps know what "higher filter" to use?

Comment: If LINEAR filter shows artifacts, then a higher filter will probably not help. Can you add a screenshot of the artifacts?

Comment: It seems like the texture is loaded at a lower (or maybe even higher) resolution than the original. Can you check this?

Comment: When I take a look at the texture in PIX, it looks fine so it appears the texture is loaded just fine.

Comment: I get almost the same result as the light blue row if I threshhold your origin image at 128. Are the black pixels in your origin image at 0 alpha? What alpha blend settings are you using?